# Avoiding adding a duplicate

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am learning EF. I have code that looks as below.

I added the Key annotations because when I add a symbol, it should be added once and no more. So if add EUR/USD, I don't want a different EUR/USD. However, on different runs of this program, when I run the code, it complains that the key is already there. How do either created the context if it is not already in the db, or get a reference to it if it already exists?

```
 using (var db = new TickDataTestContext())
            {
                var td = new SymbolTickDataEntity { Symbol = symbol };
                db.SymbolTickData.Add(td);
                db.SaveChanges();

                while (true)
                {
                    etc....


public class SymbolTickDataEntity
{
    public int SymbolTickDataEntityID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<MarketDataDepthEntity> Mdds { get; set; }
    public SymbolTickDataEntity() { Mdds = new List<MarketDataDepthEntity>(); }
}

public class TickDataTestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MarketDataEntity> MarketData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MarketDataDepthEntity> MarketDataDepth { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SymbolTickDataEntity> SymbolTickData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check SymbolTickData to see if that exists before inserting it.

```
    if(!db.SymbolTickData.Any(a => a.Symbol.Equals(symbol)))
    {
         db.SymbolTickData.Add(td);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
```